# How to pass argv arguments to a C program using a file or python script in linux?

Tags: python, c, arguments, programming

I used to be able to pass input to C program by first writing a python script and using pipe to send it to the C program  as an input

or write the output of python script to a file and just doing r < myfile in gdb

but how can i do this to pass argv arguments to a C function?

i need to pass a long argument and need to use print function of python to create the value, but i don't know how can i pass it to the C program? piping or using < doesn't work.

for example doing python x.py | myprogram didn't work, and using it after the myprogram like myprogram python x.py doesn't work either, how can i pass the output as an argv argument of this program?

Comment: If you used to be able to run `python script.py | cprog`, then `cprog` was reading from stdin. Why is this no longer a valid solution for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you’re looking for

```
myprogram "$(python x.py)"
```

This will take the script’s output and use it as the first argument to `myprogram` (`argv[1]`).

To use the contents of a file as the first argument to `myprogram`, `cat` the file instead:

```
myprogram "$(cat file)"
```

Comment: And how can i use a text file as an input? pipe doesn't work

Comment: You want to have the contents of a text file in `argv[1]`, is that right?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: See the update.